# Serializer for data class Kotlin not found at build release

Tags: android, kotlin, serializable, kotlinx.serialization

I want convert my json string response from API to object:

```
val obj = Json.decodeFromString<MyModel>(jsonResponseString)
```

My data class:

```
@Serializable
data class MyModel(
    @SerializedName("field") val field: String
)
```

It look like very simple and it works on debug mode!

But when a compiled the AppBundle, builded in release mode and download app from Play Store internal testing, I got the following error :

```
Serializer for class '...' is not found. Mark the class as @serializable or provide the 
serializer explicitly.
kotlinx.serialization.internal.Platform_commonKt.serializerNotRegistered
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the next solution:

First step, I added @Keep anotation. Keep anotation denotes that the annotated element should not be removed when the code is minified at build time:

```
@Keep
@Serializable
data class MyModel(
    @SerializedName("field") val field: String
)
```

Second step, I converted my json to object making a static reference to the serializer:

```
val objError = Json {ignoreUnknownKeys = true}.decodeFromString(MyModel.serializer(), jsonResponseString)
```

Dont forget import and implement last version of:

```
'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
```

And it worked and it save my day!!

Comment: You saved the day!

Answer (score 14):

You should add this to your proguard.pro if you're using `minifyEnabled true`

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*, InnerClasses
-dontnote kotlinx.serialization.AnnotationsKt # core serialization annotations

# kotlinx-serialization-json specific. Add this if you have java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObjectSerializer
-keepclassmembers class kotlinx.serialization.json.** {
    *** Companion;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class kotlinx.serialization.json.** {
    kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}

# Change here com.yourcompany.yourpackage
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.yourcompany.yourpackage.**$$serializer { *; } # <-- change package name to your app's
-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.yourpackage.** { # <-- change package name to your app's
    *** Companion;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.yourcompany.yourpackage.** { # <-- change package name to your app's
    kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}
```

Make sure you replace the placeholder package name with your app package name

[Source](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#android)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed that with these changes in the Gradle files, in the build project gradle add this line to dependencies:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.5.21"
```

Add also these to the build app gradle:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlinx-serialization'
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.2'
}
```

Please note version numbers might be different.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 1.5.0-RC proguard rules are shipped with library.

> **Bundled Proguard rules**
> The kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm JAR file now includes consumer Proguard >rules,
> so manual Proguard configuration is no longer necessary for most of the setups.